# How should I manage a table with lots of rows that are inserted and removed each hour?

Tags: mysql

I have to temporarily store lots of data in a table, an hour at a time. For example, each hour I write 20k (or some other large number) of records. I do some stuff with that data during the hour, and by the end of the hour the table is empty again. At the start of the new hour, I add 20k more records and continue the process.

I'm currently storing the data in a MySQL table with an INT auto-increment primary key.

Eventually, I will run out of numbers and I'm looking for a solution that solves the problem, rather than postpones it (e.g. using unsigned BIG INT). I can think of several solutions, but I'm not sure what the consequences are of each - specifically the effects on MySQL. For example, will doing this a particular way cause table corruption or performance problems, etc.

How should problems like this be solved?

1. Create and remove the table each hour
2. Reset the auto-increment column each hour
3. Do either #1 or #2, but at longer intervals
4. Don't use an auto-increment key (I can easily insert my own sequential key)
5. Other?

NOTE: For processing purposes, it doesn't matter that the key is re-used each hour. I only use it to distribute the processing of the data.

Comment: @Ben: Care to elaborate?

Comment: int unsigned gives you 24.5 years (4294967295 / 175200000 p/yr)

Comment: My data needs will scale up rather quickly. 20k per day was just an example.

Comment: Let me put it this way: If you follow my example and use a _SERIAL_, you can put 5.8 billion records/second, and still not run out during the next 100 years. Is it really better to get your hands dirty and clean the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want to empty the table,  you should use the [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) command, which efficiently wipes out the data and indexes, leaving the table structure intact.

Answer (score 1):

When you empty the table, reset its auto-increment counter:

```
ALTER TABLE foo AUTOINCREMENT = 1;
```

Clearing the rows from the table leaves the counter where it was, and eventually you run out of key space as you indicated. If you reset this counter, and it doesn't matter as each hour is a new set of data, this seems the most effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you forgot to mention something you won't run out of numbers any time soon... If the amount of records written stays at 20k records/hour you'll have 12+ years with your current implementation.

And if that is not enough:

Using a *SERIAL* (alias for *BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE*) and adding about 20k records/hour will still give you over 100 billion years to play with; without having to alter tables or reset the *AUTOINCREMENT*.

Comment: int unsigned gives you 24.5 years worth